# Find Number Of Square Roots Between Two Numbers

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I have written this function for finding the number of Square Roots between two numbers (inclusive).

```
static int FindRoot(int no1, int no2) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int x = no1; x <= no2; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= no2; y++) {
            if (y * y == x)
                res++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

This will work fine, but I was thinking about it's performance.
Because in this case the `inner For loop` will execute from starting position(1), so it'll take time if someone passes a large number range to the method.

So, my question is:

> Is there any other way i can find this with better performance?

P.S.- I can't use `Math.sqrt()` function

Comment: Your function only works for perfect square roots?

Comment: You could work around the rules and implement [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number) for computing the square root... but that's probably not what you want :P

Comment: i hope so,it's working for few cases i tested. Is there any problem then help me to find out.

Comment: SamYounnou had a good idea

Comment: Well for starters, you can remove the outer loop and do a range check; instead of checking each number for equality.

Comment: You can also break your inner loop when the condition `y * y <= no2` is false

Comment: An even cheekier evasion of the rules: `Math.exp(0.5 * Math.log(x))` is mathematically equivalent to `Math.sqrt(x)` for `x>0`, although you will likely end up with a minor difference in the decimal when doing it with a computer.

Comment: @SamYonnou: So evil, yet, so good!  I was thinking about starting the loop at `x = no1 > 0 ? 1 << Math.getExponent(no1)/2 : 0`, which is a similar level of evilness.

Comment: @AJNeufeld or use something like the ["fast inverse square root"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code) approximation, so as to obfuscate the bending of the rules...

Comment: @SamYonnou: Come to think of it, the counting is really unnecessary.  We simply need `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(no2)) - Math.ceiling(Math.sqrt(no1)) + 1`.  If we can implement `floor(sqrt(no2))` and `ceiling(sqrt(no1))` in a quick "legal" fashion, such as a binary search, the "count" becomes just a subtraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static int FindRoot(int no1, int no2) {
    int res = 0;
    int x = 0;

    // Ignore squares less than no1
    while(x*x < no1) {
        x++;
    }

    // Count squares up to and including no2
    while(x*x <= no2) {
        res++;
        x++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get away with having a single for loop by getting rid of the outer loop

```
static int findRoot(int lo, int hi) {
    int numRoots = 0;

    for (int x = 0, x2 = 0; x2 <= hi; x++, x2 = x * x) {
        if (x2 >= lo) {
            numRoots++;
        }
    }    

    return numRoots;
}
```

here you effectively just do your inner loop once, incrementing `numRoots` when `x2` (x-squared) is between `lo` and `hi`, and terminating the loop when `x2` is greater than `hi` (instead of when `x` is greater than `hi` like in your code).

Comment: You miss counting zero as a possible square-root.  Start with "x=0, x2=0".

Answer (score 0):

It'll work as well.

```
static int FindRoot2(int no1, int no2) {
    int res = 0;
    int inner=1;
    for (int x = no1; x <= no2; x++) {
        for (int y = inner; y <= no2; y++) {
            if (y * y == x)
            {
                inner=y;
                res++;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

In this case inner loop will not start executing from 1.

Comment: This does do a bit of optimization, but there is no reason to use a solution besides the clear, straightforward O(n) solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why your current algorithm is ineffecient, but the biggest one is that the inner for loop is not necessary.

The idea behind the algorithm you're looking for, is to start at the lowest perfect square higher than or equal to no1, then go to the next perfect square and the next and the next, keeping track of how many you hit, until the perfect square you're on is higher than no2.

```
static int FindRoot(int no1, int no2) {

    int res = 0;
    int x = 1;

    // This loop gets x to the first perfect square greater than
    // or equal to no1
    while( (x * x) < no1 ) {
        x++;
    }

    // This loop adds 1 to res and increases x
    // as long as x^2 is less than or equal to no2
    for(; (x * x) <= no2; x++, res++) { }

    return res;
}
```